# Nodejs Axios Bad Request 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to post results from a query in nodejs to an enpoint. When i do a post with postman with the expected parameters, i get a successful response, but when i use axios i keep getting an error

```
data: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n' +
     '<html><head>\n' +
     '<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n' +
     '</head><body>\n' +
     '<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n' +
     '<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n' +
     '</p>\n' +
     '<hr>\n' +
     '<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>\n' +
     '</body></html>\n'
```

My code looks like this

```
//check unsent appointments
                    connection.query("select * from appointments where processed=0 ", function (err, results, fields) {
                        
                        if(err) {console.log(err)};
        
                        var test = results.forEach(result => {

                            console.log(result);

                            axios.post('test.co.ke/hl7-sync-appointment', result)
                            .then(function (response){
                                console.log(response.data)

                                //update status of updated appointment
                                result = connection.query("update appointments set processed ='1', date_processed ='"+DATE_TODAY+"', send_log='" +response.data +"' where id="+result.id+" ")
                            })
                            .catch(function (error){

                                console.log(error )

                                //update appointment with error
                                result = connection.query("update appointments set date_processed ='"+DATE_TODAY+"', send_log='" +error +"' where id="+result.id+" ")

                            })
                            
                        });

                    });
```

Any assistance/recommendations will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alternate api of axios.
Mainly You need to check what is the difference between what data you are sending in postman and what you are missing when you are sending through axios().
If possible, please share the request structure from POSTMAN.

And here is the other alternative.

```
    var options = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'yourURL',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "attrName": AttrValue
    }),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // or what ever you have used
        'Authorization': 'Beared', // or what ever you have used
    }
   };
   let response = await axios(options);

    if (response.status == 200) {
        // Done
    } else {
        // Error
    }
```

You can also debug your 'result' variable in for loop. The issue might be with that variable. It might not be in correct format which axios is expecting.